# Running cron for nodejs and deleting files in temp

Tags: linux, node.js, cron

I'm trying to run nodejs /var/www/html/back/elastic/users.js g command every 10 minutes in cron but I don't seem to be able to

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin nodejs /var/www/html/back/elastic/users.js
```

I've added this to crontab -e but when I check syslog it doesn't show there.

Same for the following command I want to delete files in temp every day, it doesn't work either

```
30 2 * * * rm -rf /var/www/html/data/users/temp/*
```

What am I missing? Thanks for any help

Ubuntu Server 15.04

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/local/nodejs /var/www/html/back/elastic/users.js
```

and

```
30 2 * * * /bin/rm -rf /var/www/html/data/users/temp/*
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I will try it as you mentioned and report back here

Answer (score 0):

You should try removing the space from the first crontab

*/10 * * * * /usr/local/bin/nodejs /var/www/html/back/elastic/users.js

the second command looks correct to me, is the path correct? Maybe a permission issue. 
It should delete everything under /var/www/html/data/users/temp/ at 2:30am

Comment: The first command seems to be working now I am also receiving log mails about it

For the second one when I run the command from terminal to test it, it does delete the contents of the temp folder. But cron doesn't seem to be working neither am I receiving an email about it because I have defined MAILTO="mymail"